# External command is not recognized by VSCODE Tasks

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am just trying to execute a simple shell file from VS-Code [tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) functionality.

My `tasks.json` file

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [  
    {
        "label": "Run-some-custom-script",
        "detail": "Prepare some ENV variables for the deployment",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "./scripts/mlflow.sh",
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": false
        }
    }
]
}
```

And my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mlflow server \
   --host 0.0.0.0 \
   --port 5000 \
   --backend-store-uri sqlite:///C:\\mlflow-server\\mlruns.db \
   --default-artifact-root file:///C:\\mlflow-server\\artifacts \
```

But every time I am getting error like -
[image: Command not recognized]

Though the command is perfectly fine If I try to execute is from the poweshell itself.

What I tried so far:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [  
    {
        "label": "Run-some-custom-script",
        "detail": "Prepare some ENV variables for the deployment",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "mlflow servre",
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": false
        }
    }
]
}
```

And:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [  
    {
        "label": "Run-some-custom-script",
        "detail": "Prepare some ENV variables for the deployment",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\mlflow.exe servre",
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": false
        }
    }
]
}
```

**But, still the same, I have also tried to change my default terminal in VS code. But No luck**

Can anyone give me any hints - why is this happening and where I should look further ?

Comment: You are mixing Bash and Powershell. Is that intentional?

Comment: I have installed the git bash in my pc. Also I though about the same mixing both could be a problem,  But I tied to change my VS-Code terminal to git bash. But the result was still the same

Comment: Did you already try to [specify the shell](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_common-questions) to be bash for the bash-part?

Comment: Yes I did, From the VS-Code setting. But still the same

Answer (score 0):

Its Funny :) But I just restart my PC and VS-Code. Wholly, Its working.